# "Too few arguments" error trying to run my compiled program

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I'm trying to code to refresh my memory preparing myself for a course.

```
int main(){

  int x;

  for( x = 0;x < 10; x++){
    printf("Hello world\n");
  }

  return 0;

}
```

But when I tried to run this I get `Too few arguments`

I compiled the code above using `gcc -o repeat file.c` Then to run this I just type `repeat`

Sorry if this was a stupid question, it has been a while since I took the introduction class.

Comment: Thank you. I hope we didn't get side tracked. Really interested in the answer.

Comment: Can you show *exactly* what you typed to compile and run this, and the complete output from the compiler and executable?

Comment: In general you should be more precise when asking questions, meaning you should tell us exactly where the error occured and when in doubt the exact error message. you should always try to make the work of those you want to help you as easy as possible. Besides it works just as it should (here)[http://ideone.com/zf7KO], so there is nothing wrong with the code. Do you get an error trying to invoke the compiler?

Comment: @ Grizzly Thanks for the tip. Since I'm taking a c class right now for electrical engineering. You'll see me here more often. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: You need to add `#include <stdio.h>` at the top.  Less importantly, `int main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your code compiles fine](http://ideone.com/vS9vw). Try:

```
gcc -o helloworld file.c
./helloworld
```

Comment: That's what he said.  "when I tried to ***run*** this I get `Too few arguments`"

Comment: @BenVoigt Run what? The .c file? It's ambigious as to exactly what he's doing, I tried to make my answer cover everything.

Comment: What he ran is the question, isn't it.  But he didn't say he had problems compiling, so no surprise it compiles fine for you too.

Comment: @BenVoigt I feel a beginner is not unlikely to say something along the lines of *When I try to **run** `code snippet` I get `prog.cpp:9: error: expected \`;' before ‘while’`*. So I'm just covering all the bases.

Answer (score 2):

When you type

```
filename
```

at a prompt, your OS searches the path.  By default, Linux doesn't include the current directory in the path, so you end up running something like `/bin/filename`, which complains because it wants arguments.  To find out what file you actually ran, try

```
which filename
```

To run the `filename` file gcc created in the working directory, use

```
./filename
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE :**

Based on more recent comments, the problem is that the executable is named `repeat`, and you're using csh or tcsh, so `repeat` is a built-in command.

Type `./repeat` rather than `repeat`.

And when asking questions, don't omit details like that; copy-and-paste your source code, any commands you typed, and any messages you received.

---

The executable is named `file`, which is also a command.

To run your own program, type

```
./file
```

**EDIT :**

The above was an educated guess, based on the assumption that:

- The actual compilation command was `gcc file.c -o file` or `gcc -o file file.c`; and
- The predefined `file` command (`man file` for information) would produce that error message if you invoke it without arguments.

The question originally said that the compilation command was `gcc file.c`; now it says `gcc -o filename file.c`.  (And the `file` command prints a different error message if you run it without arguments).

The *correct* way to do this is:

```
gcc file.c -o filename && ./filename
```

(I'd usually call the executable `file` to match the name of the source file, but you can do it either way.)

The `gcc` command, if it succeeds, gives you an executable file in your current directory named `filename`.  The `&&` says to execute the second command only if the first one succeeds (no point in trying to run your program if it didn't compile).  `./filename` explicitly says to run the `filename` executable that's in the current directory (`.`); otherwise it will search your `$PATH` for it.

If you get an error message `Too few arguments`, it's not coming from your program; you won't see that message unless something prints it explicitly.  The explanation must be that you're running some other program.  Perhaps there's already a command on your system called `filename`.

So try doing this:

```
gcc file.c -o filename && ./filename
```

and see what happens; it *should* run your program.  If that works, try typing just

```
filename
```

and see what that does.  If that *doesn't* run your program, then type

```
type -a filename
```

or

```
which filename
```

to see what you're actually executing.

And just to avoid situations like this, cultivate the habit of using `./whatever` to execute a program in the current directory.

Comment: Except when it's called `a.out`.

Comment: If compiled with `gcc file.c`, then the executable will be called `a.out`. http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2002-04/msg00075.html

Comment: If I compile a simple hello world and name it "filename" to run it all I had to do was type "filename" I didn't need the "./" in front. Why is that?

Comment: Lol this is caused because I name the file "repeat" and I didn't realize that repeat is a shell built-in command. Thanks for the information, Keith Thompson.

Comment: @user101699: This is why you should show us *exactly* what your program looks like, *exactly* what commands you typed, and *exactly* what error messages you got (copy-and-paste, don't re-type).  If you had said in your original question that typing `repeat` printed `repeat: Too few arguments`, we could have saved a lot of time.  (Apparently you're using csh or tcsh; `repeat` isn't a shell built-in command in `sh` or `bash`.)

Comment: Yes, but it's much better to copy and paste text.